# "Compiling" and "compilation" tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I notice there are tags like `compiling` and `compilation` which are very similar. When I click on `compilation`, it autodirects to `compiling`, so it seems they have been merged like some other sets of tags. However, would it be cleaner for the site if we could somehow delete one of the tags after absorbing it into the other instead of keeping both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the autocompletion list, it says ”compiling (78)” and “compilation (s)”. This means that [compiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compiling) is used on 78 questions and [compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compilation) is a synonym. On the [tags page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags) both are listed and [compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compilation) redirects to [compiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compiling). I believe there is no other place on TeX.SX where [compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compilation) is visible.

Tag synonyms are useful for at least two reasons:

- They don't let users recreate the duplicate tag by ignoring the autocompletion list (e.g. by just typing `compilation` into the tag field). Similarly, they make the tag easier to find (e.g. if you start typing `compila`, you will still get a correct autocompletion suggestion).
- They provide a synonym in searches.

While having both versions in the autocompletion list and the tag list page is a bit confusing, I think that synonyms are generally useful for the site.